# Intel Vtune hotspot can not see source code (only assembly code )

Tags: mpi, intel, profiler, hpc, intel-vtune

in intel vtune hotspots can not see the source code , there is only assembly code , i want to analyse my code and do the profiling .
what should i do to get the hotspots in my source code ?
here is the image of my profiler interface :
[image]

i did try to change the  makefile ,the flag "-g" to "-g3", it doesn't change anything
here is my makefile : `

```
FC= mpiifort

FFLAGS= -v -fp-stack-check -shared-intel -mcmodel large  
MYLIB= LIBROUTE.a
home1 = /media/sarah/HP x755w/
LIBDIR= $(home1)/ROUTE/lib
MODDIR= $(home1)/ROUTE/include


MODSRC= modd_config.F90 modd_const_grid.F90 modd_namel_config.F90 \
        modd_site_param.F90 modd_model_param.F90 modd_diag_param.F90

SUBRSRC= subp.F90 read_namel_config.F90 read_aladin_prev.F90 read_arome_prev.F90 \
        read_dust_prev.F90 interpol_aladin_prev.F90 interpol_arome_prev.F90 \
        interpol_dust_prev.F90 interpol_nebul_ald_prev.F90 interpol_nebul_aro_prev.F90 \
        calcul_meteo_prev.F90 calcul_meteo_aro_prev.F90 write_meteo_param.F90
MASTERSRC= prev_route.F90


MODOBJ=    $(MODSRC:.F90=.o)
MODMOD=    $(MODSRC:.F90=.mod)          
SUBROBJ=   $(SUBRSRC:.F90=.o)
MASTEROBJ= $(MASTERSRC:.F90=.o) 
    
#RPT= $(SRC:.F90=.optrpt)
EXE= PREV_ROUTE
CLEAN+= $(MODOBJ) $(MODMOD) $(SUBROBJ) $(MASTEROBJ) $(MYLIB) $(EXE)


#MOD= *.mod
#SMOD= *.smod

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES:      .F90 .o .x

#build: $(OBJ)
#           $(MODMOD) $(OBJ) $(EXE)
module:
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $(MODSRC)

#ar -cvq $(MYLIB) $(MODOBJ)

subr:   
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c  $(SUBRSRC)  

master:
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c  $(MASTERSRC)

all:    
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $(MODSRC) $(SUBRSRC) $(MASTERSRC)
#.F90.o: 
#   $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $< $(OBJ)   
#.o.x:
#exe:
#   $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -o $(EXE) $(MODOBJ) $(SUBROBJ) $(MASTEROBJ)

libss:
    ar crs $(MYLIB) $(MODOBJ) $(SUBROBJ)

exe:
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(MASTEROBJ) $(MYLIB) -g3 -O0  -o $(EXE) -lmpifort
#mpiifort prev_route.F90 lib/LIBROUTE.a -o PREV_ROUTE_LIB


clean: 
    \rm -f $(CLEAN)
```

'
`and here is the collection log  (warnings) :
[image]

Comment: Note that the optimisation level can have an impact on this, and some options like `-fomit-frame-pointer`. Moving sources can also have an impact as well as how the code is actually compiled.

Comment: Do you have source code for `libifcoremt.so.5`?  Your screenshot seems to be showing that as the current tab, so does that mean the machine code you're looking at is from that library?

Comment: @PeterCordes u can find my makefile and the collection log warning , and the principle source code is in prev_route.F90